# PostGIS raster table: How to get the global maximum (or minimum) value?

Tags: postgis, raster

Is there any straightforward and efficient way to get the global maximum (or minimum) value for a given band from a raster table in PostGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer: ST_SummaryStatsAgg (http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SummaryStatsAgg.html) function does the job. However, It is pretty slow for very large rasters. If someone knows a more efficient way to handle large rasters stats with PostGIS, I'm interested!